# Unable to set FQDN in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: dns, hostname

The instructions I have found say to edit the `/etc/hostname` file and add the hostname, without the domain portion.  To set the domain portion, I should edit `/etc/hosts` and add an entry that looks something like this:

```
127.0.0.1 myhostname.domain.tld myhostname
```

I created the entries as suggested and rebooted the system.  The command `hostname` correctly shows the hostname without domain.  However, the command `hostname -f` does NOT show the FQDN (`myhostname.domain.tld`).  This command also shows the unqualified hostname only (`myhostname`).

The instructions on how to do this are clearly incorrect for Ubuntu 22.04.  What is the correct way to do this?

Additional question.  Does it matter as long as the DNS server in my network correctly resolves `myhostname.domain.tld` to my server's IP address?

Comment: The domain is assigned by the search domain on your system when you have a DHCP or network connection.  The FQDN does not have to match the system hostname (case in point: my laptop on my network has a local hostname of `tau-volantis` but on network it has a FQDN that the system doesn't know about except by search domain - `tau-volantis.admin.thomas-ward.internal` - that is determined by the local search domain assigned to it).  It ultimately doesn't matter though - only that public DNS works for it. The `/etc/hosts` entry will tell the system to use itself for that FQDN.

Comment: Well score another point for Microsoft obfuscation techniques :-/.

Answer (score 0):

I did discover that `hostname -A` and `hostname -a` does reply with my fqdn (e.g., server.acme.com).

I also discovered this blurb on another website:

> If it’s not connected with a domain, then only the hostname will be displayed.

**Reference:**

- https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/domains/domain-administration/fqdn-fully-qualified-domain-name/